# MySQL update Query using Select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Can someone explain how to write an update query to update a column "newBalance" in table "abcd" with the O/P of balance in the following query ?

I would like to update newBalance column with the balance calculated for each row using the below query.

```
SELECT id
     , inAmt
     , outAmt
     , @prev := if(id = 1, @prev := @curBalance , @prev + (@prevOut-@prevIn)) as balance
     , @prevIn :=inAmt
     , @prevOut := outAmt 
  from (select @prev := 0) as i
     , abcd 
 order 
    by id
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Gordon, 
Thanks for the reply.
I'm able to get the desired results using the above select query. But I would like to combine the above query with update query to update a column called "newBalance" using the value of calculated balance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with a `join`:

```
update abcd join
       (select id, inAmt, outAmt,
               @prev := if(id = 1, @prev := @curBalance , @prev + (@prevOut-@prevIn)) as balance,
               @prevIn := inAmt,
               @prevOut := outAmt
        from (select @prev := 0) as i cross join
             abcd
        order by id
       ) x
       on abcd.id = x.id
    set abcd.newbalance = x.balance;
```

All that said, your query is definitely not guaranteed to work and can fail at any time.  You are using variables in one expression and assigning them in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.

However, that was not the question that you asked.  If you want the query fixed, ask a new question with sample data and desired results.